# Status bar for csv file read

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, python-2.7

**Edit:** Answer is below.  `self.progress.update_idletasks()` was the secret handshake to have the progress bar update.  Thanks mgilson.

I am currently working with some somewhat large csv files (sometimes up to 700Mb), and it takes a while (pulling from a network drive).  I would like to be able to give the user some feed back as the the status of the process.  This led me to the ttk statusbar. I have looked at as many examples as I could find, and then tried to apply them to my program with no success.  I think my problem is that I am using a `for` loop to read my csv file, but that might not be the issue.  I don't know.  Below is an example of how my code works.

```
import csv
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class MAIN(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        n=0
        self.filename = 'some.csv'
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        frame=tk.Frame(master, **kwargs)
        frame.grid()
        getdata = tk.Button(frame, text='Get Data', command=self.csvget)
        getdata.grid(row=n)
        n+=1
        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(frame, orient='horizontal',
                                        length =200, mode='determinate')
        self.progress.grid(row=n)
    def prog(self):
        self.progress['value']=0
        try: f=open(self.filename, 'rb')
        except: return
        read = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        self.maxrows=0
        for row in read: self.maxrows+=1
        self.progress['maximum']=self.maxrows
    def csvget(self):
        try: f=open(self.filename, 'rb')
        except: return
        read = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        q=0
        for row in read:
            if q%100==0: self.progress['value']=q
            elif q==self.maxrows: self.progress['value']=q
            ... do some stuff (read into lists etc.)...

root=tk.Tk()
app=MAIN(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Well that turned out longer than I expected.  I know I am reading the file twice. (I couldn't figure out how to get the length of the csv file any other way, if you have a solution for this I am all ears.)  But the main thrust of of my question remains how do I get the progress bar to work.  In its current configuration it goes from zero to full instantly as soon as the file is done reading.  Suggestions?

**Edit:** My code has gotten much better with mgilson's help.  However my status bar still does not update while the file.  I have tried the following:

```
self.completed = tk.IntVar()
self.completed.set(0)
self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self.frame, orient='horizontal', length=200,
                   mode='determinate', maximum=100, variable=self.completed)
#in the function now
fsize = os.path.getsize(self.filename)
for r,row in enumerate(read):
    q=float(f.tell())/float(fsize)*100 
    if r%100 ==0:
        self.completed.set(q)
```

Also rather than just calling `self.completed` I made a `def` that took `q` as an input and then put it into `self.completed`.  Also rather than using `self.completed` I got rid of the `variable` kwarg in `self.progress` and went back to calling the kwarg 'value' in both directly and through the `def`.  Also attempted was `self.progress.configure(value = q)` and it behaves just as the others.

All of these tries only refresh the bar after the file has completed.

If I modify the bar's status before the `for` loop where the data is read but in the same `def` the bar does not get updated until the file is done reading.  (I tried to set it to 50 as an experiment, it went from none to 100% as soon as the file completed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like:

```
if q%100==0: 
    self.progress['value']=float(q)/100
    self.progress.update_idletasks()
```

or perhaps:

```
self.progress.configure(value=q)
self.progress.update_idletasks()
```

with the previous version, as soon as you read 100 lines, the progress bar will get filled up.

Also note that the progress bar will only get updated once program control returns to the mainloop unless you explicitly tell it otherwise (with `update_idletasks()`).

As far as not reading the file twice, you **might** be able to use `file.tell` for that (no guarantees -- let me know if it doesn't work and I'll delete this suggestion):

```
fsize=os.path.getsize(filename)
...
q=f.tell()/fsize
```

If this works, you may be able to change your constructor to:

```
self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(frame, orient='horizontal',
                                length =200, mode='determinate',maximum=1.)
```

and your loop to:

```
for i,row in enumerate(read):
    q=f.tell()/fsize
    if i%100==0: 
        self.progress['value']=q
        self.progress.update_idletasks()
    #do stuff
else:
    self.progress['value']=q
    self.progress.update_idletasks()
```

One other side note, it is generally not a good idea to have a bare `try/except` clause.  You usually want:

```
try:
   #something
except SomeError: #IOError?  OSError? some combination of the two of them?
   #something else.
```

catching only the exceptions you know how to handle.

Comment: I am working on applying what you have there.  In the loop call how would I call say the 5th element in a row?  still row[4]?  I have not seen this format before.

Comment: @deadstump.  Yes.  `enumerate` just wraps around any iterator and returns the index and then the element.  In this case, the elements are rows (lists), so you can use the variable `row` exactly the way you used it before.

Comment: The bounding on the file size works great and saves me from opening the file twice.  However the progress bar still does not update its self while it is getting the file.  I did a little experiment, and tried to have the bar reset its self at the beginning of the call `['value']=0`.  It didn't.  Is there something that prevents the bar from refreshing while in a different def call?

Comment: @deadstump -- The docs on this class are quite sparse, so it's a little hard to pin down.  Anyway, I've added another suggestion which might help...

Comment: I have tried the set variable method both in line and kicking it out to a separate def (I had to multiply by 100 and make the max 100 because it was an int).  I have also tried going back to the 'value' way.  But for all cases it does not update until the file is done reading (I can make it print values during the read).  I am at a loss as to what to do.  I will add this info to an edit.

Comment: @deadstump -- did you try the `.configure` way?

Comment: The `.configure` way works the same as the others.  (I hadn't tried it until after your message... missed that one.)

Comment: @deadstump -- One last attempt.  Try adding `self.progress.update_idletasks()` right after you update it.  Otherwise, I tried my hand at rolling my own StatusBar which you're free to use.

Comment: Hot damn!  The `self.progress.update_idletasks()` worked like a charm!  Thank you very much for helping so much!

Comment: @deadstump -- Apparently the tasks don't get updated until you hit the mainloop unless you explicitly tell them to update otherwise.

Comment: Apparently.  You should update your answer to highlight this fact.  Thanks again.